# Return the last 2 digits a number

Tags: php

How can I get the last 2 digits of:

```
<departureDate>200912</departureDate>
```

to my object:

```
$year = $flightDates->departureDate->year;
```

Comment: is it `$flightDates->departureDate->year` that returns  `<departureDate>200912</departureDate>`

Comment: Dont think so. Looks like the number is extracted from XML

Comment: Take a look into the date() function and the strtotime() function at php.net.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
// first two
$year = substr($flightDates->departureDate->year, 0, 2);
// last two
$year = substr($flightDates->departureDate->year, -2);
```

But given the fact that you're parsing a date here it would be smarter to use the date function.
p.e. `strtotime()` and `date()` or even:

```
<?php
$someDate ='200912';
$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', $someDate);
echo $dateObj->format('Y');
// prints "2012" .. (see date formats)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just address it as string, the function `substr` will convert it automatically:

```
<?php

//$year = '200912';
$year = $flightDates->departureDate->year;

echo substr( $year, -2 );

?>
```

Take a closer look at [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function. If you want the result to be a strict integer, then just add `(int)` in front of the return.

But, as [Jan.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/433075/jan) said, you should better work with it as a date:

```
<?php

//$year = '200912';
$year = $flightDates->departureDate->year;

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'dmy', $year );

echo date( "y", $date->getTimestamp() );

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

For numbers, you could use php's modulo function (http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php):

```
<?php
//$year = '200912';
$year = $flightDates->departureDate->year;

echo $year % 100;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a basic aritimethic operation, like this...

```
while ( $var > 100 ) 
{
    $var = (int) $var / 10;
}
```

There could be a better solution but this one will fit fine

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 : You can just strip the tags with `strip_tags` and use `substr`

```
$number = '<departureDate>200912</departureDate>' ;
$year = substr(strip_tags($number), 0,2);
var_dump($year);
```

Example 2 : You can also use `simplexml_load_string` with `substr`

```
$number = '<departureDate>200912</departureDate>' ;
$year = substr(simplexml_load_string($number),0,2);
var_dump($year);
```

Output

```
string '20' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

convert it to string. then take the first two element.

In java you can do this by following code. Let the variable is an integer named x . then you can use

```
byte[] array= Integer.toString(x).get.bytes().
```

Now array[0] and array[1] is the first two digits.
 array[array.length-1]  and  array[array.length] are the last two.

Comment: In java you can do this by following code. Let the variable is an integer named x . then you can use byte[] array= Integer.toString(x).get.bytes(). Now array[0] and array[1] is the first two digits.

Comment: Edit your answer and add this code there, don't forget to format it too.

Comment: Why are you telling how to do it in Java if the OP specified that its for PHP ?

Comment: I think it's not a matter whether you use java or php. The idea is the main thing. you can find the php equivalent functions very easily on the web. That's why !!!