# How to extract the last two digits of a number in php?

Tags: php

I have this number 12455, I want to extract the last two digits like $result = 55 .

I tried :

```
$order_id = 12455;
$lastTwoNumbers = $order_id[strlen($order_id)-2];
```

Comment: Is your requirement the same as asking for the last two _characters_ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return the last 2 digits a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639642/return-the-last-2-digits-a-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the following code:

```
$lastTwoNumbers = substr($order_id, -2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get the last two chars of that string (use a negative "*start*" parameter to count from the end):

```
<?php

$order_id = 12455;
$lastTwoNumbers = (int) substr($order_id, -2);
echo $lastTwoNumbers;
```

Will return 55. (The result will be of type string, `(int)` makes sure it will be integer after)